# Passar variável da rota para método do controller

Tags: php, laravel-4

Preciso passar uma variável de uma rota para um método do controller.

A rota:

```
Route::get('busca/{id}', 'MatriculasController@busca');
```

Como consigo passar a variável `id` para o método?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você usa como parâmetro, `slug` do seu método.

### MatriculasController.php

```
public function busca($id){

    dd($id);

}
```

Comment: Muito obrigada!

Comment: De nada! Você está usando a variável como `slug`. Mas se você utilizar como parâmetro em URL, p.e `busca?id={$id}`, você coloca no método `Input::get('id')`.